# Изменение Input Android

Tags: android, java

Приветствую, был бы безумно благодарен, если бы поделились своими методами стилизации input (изменение EditText как пример), пытался работать через селектор-тема-стиль - что-то не выходит. Help, кому не сложно.

UPD: Input свой - имеет разные дизайнерские решения слева и справа, тянется центральная часть рисунка.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/login_edittext" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/login_edittext_active" />
  <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/login_edittext_active" />
  <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/login_edittext" />
</selector>
```

Вот этот селектор прикрепляется к EditText и заменяет, но изображение (background не тянется по центру, оно просто вытягивается все в ширину и искажается).

Comment: а можно в картинках?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно не хватает только [Draw 9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html).

upd. [Подробнее](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) о технологии.

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю: в Android SDK входит утилита для создания 9-patch, которую можно запустить через %AndroidSDK%/tools/draw9patch.bat